# Running testcases in visual studio is throwing "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Recently, I moved from `.net framework` to `.net core`, Previously, when I was on the `.net framework` the unit test cases were running smoothly in visual studio. But after changing to `.net core` everything is running smoothly but on running the unit test cases the following error is being thrown:

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

with the below message being displayed on the output console:

> [26-02-2019 11:36:25 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>   [26-02-2019 11:36:26 Error] System.ArgumentException: Illegal
>   characters in path.    at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String
>   path, Boolean checkAdditional)    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String
>   path1, String path2)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.TryGetExecutablePath(String
>   executableBaseName, String& executablePath)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.GetDotnetPath()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1
>   sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1
>   sources)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria
>   testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler) [26-02-2019
>   11:36:26 Error] System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. 
>   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean
>   checkAdditional)    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String
>   path2)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.TryGetExecutablePath(String
>   executableBaseName, String& executablePath)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.GetDotnetPath()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1
>   sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1
>   sources)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria
>   testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)

I also looked at some other solution but none on them were helpful to me.

Comment: Which test framework are you use? `xUnit`, `mUnit` or `MSTest`?

Comment: NUnit and its adapter is also installed in visual studio.@Baruch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong character (like `"`) in your PATH environment variable.

You can view your PATH by running `set PATH` in **cmd**, or by enter to *Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables*.

Please share your PATH with us.

Comment: the path is `C:\Users\Admin\.dotnet\tools`, this is fine because projects other then Test project are running fine, also the testcases are running on the cli, but not through the visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

As Baruchiro wrote, in my case it was caused by `"` character in system paths.
Unfortunately when I checked that via System advance settings, the character `"` was not shown in GUI.

I had to dump it via .NET program to discover which record contains these characters:
[image]